# gtest/gmock expect call on input output pointer parameter

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mocking, googletest

I have a class such as :

```cpp
class Tcp
{
public:
    int write_data(unsigned char* data, unsigned int size);
};
```

I have a struct :

```cpp
struct Data
{
    Mode mode;
    unsigned int hardVersion;
    unsigned int softVersion;
    // etc..
}
```

which is used such as, in another class that i'm unit testing:

```cpp
{
    TestedClass::foo()
    {
        Data data;
        int control = tcpObj->write_data((unsigned char*)&data, sizeof(Data));
        // where data is filled with what's coming from write_data method, such as the mode part

        if (data.mode == Mode::A)
        {
            // operation A
        }
        else
        {
            // operation B
        }
    }
}
```

Thus I mocked, Tcp class the following way :

```cpp
class Tcp
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(int, write_data, (unsigned char* data, unsigned int size), (const));
};
```

The core of TestedClass::foo() is to do an operation based on how has been filled the parameter pointer data. So i need to be able to set what data contains after write_data call.
With gtest, how am i supposed to manually give the return value of the input ouput parameter ?

I tried the following :

```cpp
TEST(ClassUnderTest, Example)
{
    Tcp mockedTcp;
    TestedClass underTest(&mockedTcp);
    Data data;
    data.mode = Mode::B;

    EXPECT_CALL(mockedTcp, write_data(_, _)).WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgumentPointee<0>((unsigned char*)&data), Return(sizeof(Data))));
    EXPECT_CALL(/* operation B as i want Mode::B to be returned by data when write_data is called */)

    underTest.foo();
}
```

But i get the following error : /gmock-actions.h:1309:41: error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘unsigned char’ [-fpermissive]
and i can't get to understand why and how to solve it ..

Comment: `SetArgPointee` is for setting the pointed-to object (in general, it does `*arg = value;`). You need `SetArrayArgument` or custom Action.

Comment: Can you provide MCVE using this link: https://godbolt.org/z/jjqKjd4Wr ?
Anyway why not just use lambda `.WillOnce(Invoke([&](unsigned char* data, unsigned int size) { return size; });`?